# Errors thrown when adding `excludeFilters` for @ComponentScan annotation in Spring Boot while compiling by using Scala

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

```
@ComponentScan(
  basePackages = Array("com.org.tools"),
  excludeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = "com.org.tools.clients.*")})
@Component
@Profile(Array("app"))
class Application(pr: PRunner) extends CommandLineRunner {
  @Override
  def run(args: String*): Unit = {
    pRunner.run(args)
  }
}
```

The problem occurs at the excludeFilters line at the type, and pattern keyword.
is there something i am missing?
[image]

Comment: what is the `error` that is displayed? could you please add the `stacktrace`?

Comment: There is no stacktrace. this is happening while compiling. I can paste the snapshot to show what I mean

Comment: If this is a compilation error, then include the error message from the compiler. That will likely tell you exactly what is wrong and show us what issue you are dealing with.  From the coloring you are showing, there are two issues: probably the first parameter to ComponentScan.Filter is not named "type" (reserved word) and there is no parameter, in the second position, named "pattern"

Comment: @saumj I added an answer to fix your issue. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you are passing `"com.org.tools.clients.*"` as a string onyl, however reviewing a little the documentation says you need to pass an `Array of Strings`.

```
/**
* The pattern (or patterns) to use for the filter, as an alternative
* to specifying a Class {@link #value}.
* <p>If {@link #type} is set to {@link FilterType#ASPECTJ ASPECTJ},
* this is an AspectJ type pattern expression. If {@link #type} is
* set to {@link FilterType#REGEX REGEX}, this is a regex pattern
* for the fully-qualified class names to match.
* @see #type
* @see #classes
*/
String[] pattern() default {};
```

Then you should put your code by following way in order to fix it.

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = Array("com.org.tools"),
    excludeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = Array("com.org.tools.clients.*")})
```

**UPDATED USING SCALA**

As you are using `Scala` then you `type` is a `keyword` reserved then you should use backticks so that you can use it `type`.should do the following:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.{ComponentScan, Configuration, FilterType, Profile}
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
  basePackages = Array("com.org.tools"),
  includeFilters = Array(
    new ComponentScan.Filter(`type` = FilterType.ASPECTJ,
                              pattern = Array("com.org.tools.clients.*"))))
@Profile(Array("app"))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `pattern` is an unresolved symbol for me. And for `type`, it says identifier expected.

Comment: Ok I reviewed and used `Kotlin` then you need to put `ComponentScan.Filter` and not to use @, try as I updated the answer.

Comment: I am using scala

Comment: @saumj Ok I figured out it on `Scala` you can take a look my answer updated. I tested and works, so you can mark it as answer, kind regards.